# Écrit-on « sans rien trouvé » ou « sans rien trouver » ?

Tags: prépositions, conjugaison, infinitif, participe-passé

Dans la phrase suivante :

> Nous avons fouillé le hangar. Sans rien trouvé.

Est-ce que « trouvé » s'écrit « é » ou « er » ?

Answer (score 7):

Si le français est ta langue maternelle, il suffit d'utiliser un verbe synonyme qui n'est pas du premier groupe pour répondre à ce genre de questions.

> Nous avons fouillé le hangar. Sans rien découvrir.

La réponse devient évidente, non ?

Comment: Synonyme… ou pas, n'importe quel verbe du deuxième ou troisième groupe te fera deviner la réponse.

Comment: Merci, c'est bien ce qui me semblait. Il semblerait donc qu'il y ait une faute de conjugaison à la page 36 du dernier Blake et Mortimer "L'onde Septimus".

Answer (score 2):

De toute façon, l'infinitif après les prépositions (ici: sans).

Comment: À méditer. Mais de façon générale je ne prendrais pas cela *pour acquis*.